# Localhost works only in my computer and not in my local network

Tags: html, xampp, localhost, ipv4

Working on **HTML/CSS/JS** code. While i set up a localhost it works fine on my computer (*the one hosting it*) but i can't connect from any other computer on my network. I tryed (almost) everything and searched a lot throughout the last 3 days. I tryed **XAMPP** and **MAMP** but whatever i do i get the same error; "**ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT**" or "**ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED**" (**Chrome**). Im new to programming and self-tought...so in many cases i did not know exactly what i have been doing... i followed tuttorials and articles about relevant subjects but nothing came out!
At this point, i'm not even sure if what im trying to do is even possible, but many people i came accross searching said it worked for them no-problem.
Also, strange thing; "localhost" seems to work fine on my computer, while "127.0.0.1" sometimes don't. IPv4 works fine allways.

**EDIT** Found the solution, it was just my firewall blocking the apache server -_- I am dumb. Thanks for the answers & help!

Answer (score 0):

From my experience to access you're outputted code from a different computer on the same network use http://192.168.X.X where X.X is your server's local IP address. Should solve the issue. To get the ip of the computer its hosted on (permitting its windows) open up your cmd prompt and type "ipconfig" then you will get all of the neccesary ip info.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah every localhost points to 127.0.0.1 that means the machine you are using.

In your lan you should find your LAN Address and access using it.

Depending on your scenario maybe you need to set some DNS Server.